# Unable to update database by calling stored procedure with a commit inside

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I have a stored procedure like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StudentSproc
    (@StudentID VARCHAR(50),
     @Name VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRAN

  BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO Student(StudentID, Name)
    VALUES (@StudentID,@Name)
    COMMIT TRAN;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
     ROLLBACK TRAN
  END CATCH
END;
```

I am trying to execute it from python:

```
db_conn_str = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(db_conn_str)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
st = f"exec master.dbo.StudentSproc @StudentID = ?, @Name = ? "
s_id = "101"
name = "Charles"
params = (s_id, name)
cursor.execute(st, params)
print(f"executed sproc by {st}")
```

This has no errors and executes the stored procedure but it doesn't update the database and I am surprised. I know that I have to use `autocommit=True` in the `connect()` call, but why is that necessary if there is a commit in the stored procedure?

Comment: You have a good explanation based on assumptions and guesses. But as already explained, your sql code catches errors but does not re-raise them so your application (and YOU) cannot know if the insert was successful. Worse is that you apparently created a user stored procedure in the **MASTER** database (and apparently a table as well). Seems to me you have some confusion about your connection, which database you **should** be using, and what code is actually being executed.

Answer (score 0):

There are no errors because you are using a `try/catch`. This works just like it does in other languages - if you `catch` an exception, it doesn't get returned to the client. It's caught.

You can rollback the tran in the catch, and then `throw` again in order to return the error to the client.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE StudentSproc(
@StudentID VARCHAR(50),
@Name VARCHAR(50)) 
AS
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN;

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO Student(StudentID, Name)
        VALUES (@StudentID,@Name);    
    COMMIT TRAN;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
         if (@@trancount > 0) ROLLBACK TRAN; -- make sure that a transaction still exists before trying to roll back
         THROW; -- now that we have dealt with the transaction, return the error to the client
    END CATCH
  END;
```

I also just noticed you have your procedure in the `master` database. You probably don't actually want it there, `master` is a system database.

You also mentioned that you knew you had to use autocommit, but based on our discussion I understand now that you actually aren't using it, you were just wondering *why* you had to use it. This introduces a second possibility.

In SQL Server, the only commit that matters is the "outermost" commit. Any "nested" commit doesn't actually do anything other than reduce the value of `@@trancount`.

For example:

```sql
begin tran;
insert MyTable values (1);
begin tran; -- this doesn't really do anything, it just increments @@trancount
insert MyTable values (2);
commit; -- this does nothing other than decrement @@trancount
-- if we were to execute a rollback here, all of the data would be gone
commit; -- only this commit matters
```

On the other hand, `rollback` works differently. A single `rollback` will rollback *all* nested transactions, reducing the `@@trancount` value to zero.

If you start two transactions (one in the client code, one in the stored procedure), but only issue a single commit, then your "real" transaction is actually still open.

Comment: There is no error in the SP, the paranthesis error was mine when I incorrectly copied to the question.

Comment: @user2399453 Cheers, I have edited that comment out of my answer

Comment: just to be clear your answer doesnt work or explain the issue I am describing. I pasted the code exactly as I am running it now to eliminate any typos etc

Comment: @user2399453 If you passed in a `@studentid` or `@name` value which violated any kind of constraint on the table (primary key, foreign key, check constraint, datatype, etc) then the catch block would be hit, the transaction would roll back, there would be no error, and your data would not be updated, which matches the observed conditions in your question.

Comment: @user2399453 Oh, I see, you said you needed to have autocommit but did not actually have that in your code. OK, I will update my answer to account for that.

Comment: I understand your point but this is not the case. If I set autocommit=True it works so there is no error. I am trying to understand why the autocommit=True is necessary if the stored procedure already has a commit

Comment: @user2399453 Yep, I see what you are saying, I misread your original question and thought you were in fact using autocommit, but I see now you were not actually using it and were just wondering why you had to use it. I have updated my answer to explain this.